# Trying to display data to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, mern

New to React, trying to display data (inside of a bootstrap modal) from MongoDB to React with an axios ajax request. Postman shows to be correct. React throws `"TypeError: this.state.reviews.map is not a function"`, which tells me it is not an array since `.map()` is an array method, but Im saving the state as an array. Very confused on how to display data in React, can anyone give an example of how to do this correctly? Searched here, docs, google, still not understanding.

[image: Postman result]

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Rater from 'react-rater';
import './comment-styles.scss';

export class CommentBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            reviews: []
        }
        this.addReview = this.addReview.bind(this);
    };


    addReview() {
        Axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/reviews',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({ reviews: [response.data.id] })      
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/')
        .then(reviews => {
            this.setState({ reviews: reviews.data })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };



    render() {
        
        return (
            <div id="commentWrapper">
                <div className="commentHeader">
                    <h5>Leave a Rating!</h5>
                    <Rater style={{fontSize: '35px'}} />
                    <button id="submitRatingBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>

                    <form action="/breakfast-tacos" method="POST">
                        <textarea className="reviewTextBox" maxLength="250" placeholder="Write a review..." name="reviews"></textarea>
                        <button id="submitReviewBtn" type="submit" onClick={this.addReview}>Submit</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className="reviews">
                    <span className="user">
                        <h6>username:</h6>
                    </span>
                    <span className="text">
                        
                        {this.state.reviews.map((review, text) => {  
                                return (
                                    <p key={text}>
                                        {review} /*Where I want to display the data*/
                                    </p>
                                )
                            })}

                    </span>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you get if you add  `console.log(reviews.data)` before `this.setState({ reviews: reviews.data })` ?

Comment: Also, Can you show response data format of `addReview`?

Comment: @Ibra I added  `console.log(reviews.data.reviews)` before the `setState`, and it displays the data as an array in the console correctly. But when I try to map through the array it throws this error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, reviews}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` which is very confusing because it shows to be an array in the console.

Comment: @Ajeet Shah I'm not sure what you mean, Im new to the backend. But when I try to do the post request in postman it says: ` could not get response` `Error: socket hang up`.

Answer (score 1):

Response data is an object with property `reviews` which is an array, so you need to write:

```
componentDidMount() {

        Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/')
        .then(reviews => {
            this.setState({ reviews: reviews.data.reviews })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

And in JSX part:

`{review.reviews}`

because `review` is array element which is an object.

Comment: I tried this, but still no luck, I get this error: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`. I changed the key to `id`, still the same error. Also says `Check the render method of `CommentBox` component`. Very confused because the console displays the data correctly.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. But it is good to provide unique keys for performance. So, you can do: `<p key={review._id}> {review.reviews} </p>`.

Comment: Tried that, and still gives the same warning.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox to reproduce your issues?

Answer (score 0):

You are still in the array. In order to map through the array, you need to locate the object properties.

```
addReview() {
        Axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/reviews',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({ reviews: [response.data.id] })      
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/')
        .then(reviews => {
            this.setState({ reviews: reviews.data.reviews })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

You should be able to map through the array now without seeing the error.

Comment: I tried this, and I also put `console.log(reviews.data.reviews)` before the setState and it displays the data in the console as an array, but when I try to map through it in the JSX it throws a new error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, reviews}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`